# How to display multi-values for one field in a table or matrix for VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t-sql

I am trying to create a report in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 to display multiple values for a Part number.  One of the fields has multiple values for one Part number.  For example, the field UDFBFILD has the value of 1 and 2 for Part number A12345.  I want those values listed horizontally with all the other values instead of vertically.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can create a subreport for that, do a separate query for it and create a link between the two table adapters....

Comment: I've never done that.  How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using Crystal Reports?

Comment: No, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.  I am using Reporting Services under Business Intelligence.